# What is the difference between functions and data?

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

In functional programming, we tend to distinguish between data and functions, but what is the difference?

If I consider a constant, I could think of it as a function, which just returns the same value:

```
(def x 5)
```

So what is the distinction between data and a function? I fail to see the difference.

Comment: If you talk about first class pure functions, then it is the other way around: there is no distinction. What may be special about functions is that they are an opaque type.

Comment: Perhaps interesting in this regard is [SICP's section on Data as Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.5): "From the perspective of the user, an input expression such as `(* x x)` is an expression in the programming language, which the evaluator should execute. From the perspective of the evaluator, however, the expression is simply a list (in this case, a list of three symbols: `*`, `x`, and `x`) that is to be manipulated according to a well-defined set of rules. ... [T]he user's programs are the evaluator's data".

Comment: The property of Clojure that programs are written in data structures of primitive types of Clojure itself is called [homoiconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Data

- Data ***is*** a value (with a specific type).

  - For example, `5` is a value of type `Integer`, and `"abc"` is a value of type `String`. A composite value such as `[5 "abc"]` has the type `Vector`.
  - Two data values of the same type can always be compared for ***equality***.
- Data is never ***executed***. That is, the thread of control (aka program counter or PC) never enters the data structure.

### Function (aka "code")

- A function's only type is "code".

  - Two functions ***are never equal***, even if they are duplicates of each other.
- A function ***produces*** a value (with a specific type) when it is ***executed*** (possibly with arguments).

  - Execution means the ***thread of control*** enters the code data structure.  The code and data values encountered there have complete control over any side-effects that occur, as well as the return value.
  - Both ***compiled and interpreted*** code produce the same results. The only difference between them are implementation details that trade off complexity vs speed.

### Eval

- The `(eval ...)` special form accepts ***data as input*** and returns a ***function as output***. The returned function can be executed (i.e. invoked) so the thread of control enters the function.

  - For clarity, the above elides details such as the reader, etc.
  - ***Macros*** are best viewed as a ***compiler extension*** embedded within the code, and do not affect the data vs code distinction.

---

## P.S.

It occurred to me that the original question has not been fully answered. Consider the following:

```
; A Clojure Var pointing to the value 5
(def five 5)

; A Clojure Var pointing to a function that always returns the value 5
(def ->five  (fn [& args] 5))
```

and then use these 2 Vars:

```bash
five      => 5
(->five)  => 5
```

The parentheses make all the difference.

See also:

- [Brave Clojure](https://www.braveclojure.com/functional-programming/)
- [LispCast](https://lispcast.com/what-is-referential-transparency/)

Comment: If you pass a key to an immutable map data structure you might get back a value. Such a map is a value of some type. If you pass an argument to a function, you get back a value (unless it is a partial function). A function is also a value of some type. If you are in an untyped setting, this type is just the convention of the programmer. You can use the introspection means of the dynamic language to determine the type of a map at runtime, but you cannot do this with functions, because functions are opaque values. This is the main difference. Equality on the other hand isn't intrinsic to values.

Comment: (1) Treating a map as a function is just syntactic sugar for calling the `get` function.  (2) "function" is a type, just as "integer" & "string" are both types. Values of type "function" can be both consumed and returned when a function is executed. (3) The type of a map is always "map". The type of its keys & vals is unrelated to the container being a "map".

Comment: Considering that this question is tagged functional programming the answer is wrong. Functions and other data types are treated as values in FP. This is the very heart of functional programmuing: Everything gets a value, even effects.

Comment: _A function's only type is "code"._ This doesn't make sense even if put in quotes. "code" is not a type.

Comment: Not every type of value has an equality property, so equality doesn't help distinguishing functions from values.

Comment: _A function produces a value (with a specific type) when it is executed (possibly with arguments)._ This is handwavy at least. A function in the sense of FP doesn't produce values. It is an immutable mapping from input to output.

Comment: If at all this answer makes sense in terms of operational semantics, but I haven't enough CS background to assess it.

Answer (score 1):

In languages with the property of homoiconicity, code is data and data is code.
This code data duality blurs the distinction between code and data.
(I think your question is about what is the difference between `lambda` and data - if `lambda` itself is actually also just a data structure which has to be executed ...)

In homoiconic languages, data can become `lambda` (if it contains the instructions for a `lambda`) and vice versa.

So perhaps, the distinction is only by their type (function vs. any other data structure or primitive data type).